# XQuery to display two elements data at a time?

Tags: xpath, xquery

below is the xml file -

```
<Countries>
  <Country>
    <Name>India</Name>
    <Capital>New Delhi</Capital>
  </Country>
  <Country>
    <Name>USA</Name>
    <Capital>Washington DC</Capital>
  </Country>
  <Country>
    <Name>England</Name>
    <Capital>London</Capital>
  </Country>
  <Country>
    <Name>Japan</Name>
    <Capital>Tokyo</Capital>
  </Country>
  <Country>
    <Name>Srilanka</Name>
    <Capital>Colombo</Capital>
  </Country>
</Countries>
```

I have stored it in BaseX, an XMLDB. Now like plain DBs if I had stored there, I would have written simple `select` statement to retrieve the data from table. For example:

```
select name, capital from country
```

and got both the rows. Right? How can this be done using XQuery?

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: Actually you're already having the output - `<Countries>` is your result container, each `<County>` node is a result tuple and you've got the individual fields in there. What do you really want to do, what output are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expecting the output without elements then try this one

```
for $x in doc("Country")/Countries/Country
  return string-join( ($x/Name, $x/Capital), " - ")
```

The output will be -

```
`India - New Delhi USA - Washington DC England - London Japan - Tokyo Srilanka - Colombo`
```

If you want them on separate lines then, this is what you will have to use -

```
for $x in doc("Country")/Countries/Country
  return <li>{string-join( ($x/Name, $x/Capital), " - ")}</li>
```

Instead of `<li>` you can use any other relevant tag.

Comment: John-Thank You. I was looking for the same output.

Answer (score 1):

In a relational database (which you graphically describe as a "plain database") every query takes tables as its input and produces a table as its output. In an XML database, the input is XML and the output is XML. So you need to describe the XML you want to produce. Once you have done that, the answer to your question is yes: you can certainly write an XQuery to produce that output.

Comment: Can you take a little trouble to explain the last 2 lines you said above? An example would be very helpful

Comment: I'm happy to show you a query that produces the output you want if you tell me what output you want.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want a sequence of all `name` and `capital` elements:

```
 /Countries/Country/(Name|Capital)
```

The result produced by this query is:

```
<Name>India</Name>
<Capital>New Delhi</Capital>
<Name>USA</Name>
<Capital>Washington DC</Capital>
<Name>England</Name>
<Capital>London</Capital>
<Name>Japan</Name>
<Capital>Tokyo</Capital>
<Name>Srilanka</Name>
<Capital>Colombo</Capital>
```